# PHP Symfony - Form processing questions

Tags: php, symfony1

I am trying to build my own user authentication system (simply because the ones out there are too convoluted and big).

I have trouble getting to grasps with the Symfony form processing though.
Am looking at sfDoctrineGuardPlugin, but for the life of me, can't figure out, when the inputted password is converted to a SHA1 hash before being saved into the db.

Where can I read up on the form processing and automagical stuff that doctrine might do in between?  I've been looking at "A Gentle Introduction to Symfony", but it's not really helping.

I found out, it's happening somewhere in the updateObject() Method.

```
    if ($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
      $this->form->bind($request->getParameter($this->form->getName()));
      if ($this->form->isValid())
      {
        var_dump($this->form->getObject()->password);
        $this->form->updateObject();
        var_dump($this->form->getObject()->password);
      }
    }
// Prints:
// null
// string '989d88b585ce29839687f2938303e828e191ecef' (length=40)
```

But am having trouble finding the implementation of that method, and what exactly it calls/does.

Can anyone shed some light? I just want to understand what Symfony is doing in the background.  I think there's too much magic going on and the documentation is lacking sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/branches/1.3/lib/model/doctrine/PluginsfGuardUser.class.php#L33

```
  public function setPassword($password)
  {
    if (!$password && 0 == strlen($password))
    {
      return;
    }

    if (!$salt = $this->getSalt())
    {
      $salt = md5(rand(100000, 999999).$this->getUsername());
      $this->setSalt($salt);
    }
    $modified = $this->getModified();
    if ((!$algorithm = $this->getAlgorithm()) || (isset($modified['algorithm']) && $modified['algorithm'] == $this->getTable()->getDefaultValueOf('algorithm')))
    {
      $algorithm = sfConfig::get('app_sf_guard_plugin_algorithm_callable', 'sha1');
    }
    $algorithmAsStr = is_array($algorithm) ? $algorithm[0].'::'.$algorithm[1] : $algorithm;
    if (!is_callable($algorithm))
    {
      throw new sfException(sprintf('The algorithm callable "%s" is not callable.', $algorithmAsStr));
    }
    $this->setAlgorithm($algorithmAsStr);

    parent::_set('password', call_user_func_array($algorithm, array($salt.$password)));
  }
```

Comment: Man, how was I ever going to find it there? ;) So Doctrine actually calls setValue for every field when you call save()? Where can I see that in the code? (Just want to get behind the automagic). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Never dug that much into doctrine's code to be able to answer that, but I've dug enough into this plugin's code to know the answer to your original question.

Comment: Thanks. I guess will just use it like that and not ask questions ;)

Comment: @tillman: I can't fit the answer in here, but you want to read about Doctrine's accessors/mutators and look at the __set/_set/set methods on Doctrine_Record, Doctrine_Record_Abstract, and Doctrine_Access.